# Trigger a written function just when is changed just one cell of the sheet linked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, cell

I have a web page which provides free diets for everybody. These diets change according to your weight, age, sex...
So, to send (via mail and in PDF) the right diet I need to change **some** parameters of the sheet.

I have tried single triggering (onedit) but, as many cells change when including the parameters, the function runs too many times, or even collapses sending emails.

So, I need to be triggered the function just when only one cell is changed.
I am using the function sendSheetToPdfwithA1MailAdress (which I take advantage to thanks the developer)

Below is the whole code.
Could someone help me to trigger the whole function?

```
function sendSheetToPdfwithA1MailAdress(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; // it will send sheet 0 which is the first sheet in the spreadsheet.
  // if you change the number, change it also in the parameters below
  var shName = sh.getName()
  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(0, shName, sh.getRange('h1').getValue(),"test email with the address in cell A1 ", "This is it !");
}
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email,subject, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId()  
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;  
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);

MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 
      "FRWD "+subject+" (" + pdfName +")", 
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Put and if statement similar to this `if(e.range.columnStart==3)` in the beginning of the script then script will only respond to changes in that column.

Comment: Do you need the function to run when one cell is changed being this cell any cell on your sheet or do you want the function to run when a specific cell is changed (for example if cell ```A1``` is modified)?

Comment: Hi Mateo
It need to be triggered when only one cell is edited. I don´t care if A1or BJ55, But just that one. 
Because many will be changed and I don´t want the function to be triggered so many times.

Answer (score -1):

If you want your script to be triggered when **only** one cell is modified the you could use the following if condition:

```js
onEdit(e){
// your code
  if(e.range.getValues().length ==1){
  // the code you want to run when a single cell is changed
  }
}
```

This will check how many cells were modified and if only one has been changed it will run the rest of your code.

### Edit

From your information provided in the comments I understand you want to know if A1 has been changed, in that case use the following code:

```js
onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
  var shName = sh.getName();
   if(e.range.getA1Notation()=='A1'){
      sendSpreadsheetToPdf(0, shName, sh.getRange('h1').getValue(),"test email with the       adress in cell A1 ", "This is it !");   
   }
}
```

#### References

- [OnEdit events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

Comment: Thanks
This is a very interesting solution. However, not exactly the one that fits...
I do not care how many cells are changed, depending on the diet it could be changed 20 or 30. But I need to tell the script that when A1 is changed, the script needs to be triggered

Comment: I have tried this
 if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'A1') {
But it does not trigger the whole script.
It is similar to the one that you suggested. Where would you fit it to run the whole script?
Thanks again
Andrés

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. If you want to check if ```A1``` has been modified simply use ```e.range.getA1Notation() == 'A1'``` instead. Use ```==``` instead of ```===``` to match the string correctly. Also, if my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it :D

Comment: Yes I almost have it with your piece of advice. But I do not find its right possition, could you check with the code above?
I will accepted straight away

Comment: Hi ! I have edited my answer accordingly. Do you also need this to be trigger if it only happens in one specific sheet or in any?

Comment: Hi again Mateo, and sorry to not have writen again.
The answer seem very neat and straightfordward, but it doesn´t work. It is asking permission for UrlFetchApp.fetch https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
    at sendSpreadsheetToPdf(PDFDefinitiva:43:30)
    at onEdit(PDFDefinitiva:6:7)
I have been trying to obtain all the permissions with google cloud platform but it is getting harder and harder.
Thanks again for your support